# How to reference a table column value from a foreign key in Page Designer - Source - SQL Expression - Oracle Apex 22.21

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

I have a table `PRODUCTS` which keeps all the product data. And I have a table `ORDER_ITEMS` which keeps all the order items data. `ORDER_ITEMS` has a column `PRODUCT_ID` which is a foreign key to `PRODUCTS` table referencing `PRODUCT_ID`.

I've created a `MASTER DETAIL REPORT` page on Apex which shows the `ORDER_ITEMS` table report.

Right now it's showing `PRODUCT_ID`. I need the `PRODUCT_ID` column to show `PRODUCT_NAME`

[image: REPORT]

MASTER DETAIL REPORT PAGE DESIGNER
[image: MASTER DETAIL REPORT PAGE DESIGNER]

`PRODUCTS` TABLE
[image: PRODUCTS TABLE]

`ORDER_ITEMS` TABLE
[image: ORDER_ITEMS TABLE]

I've tried changing the `Source` `Type` to `SQL Expression` and tried running below but I'm getting an error.

```
select PRODUCT_NAME from PRODUCTS
where PRODUCT_ID = PRODUCT_ID
```

`ERROR: Ajax call returned server error ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row for ajax_dispatch_request.`

[image]

-------UPDATE-------

Based on Koen's answer, option 1, I've tried the below query but I am still getting the same error.

```
SELECT PRODUCTS.PRODUCT_NAME
FROM PRODUCTS
INNER JOIN ORDER_ITEMS_LOCAL
ON ORDER_ITEMS_LOCAL.PRODUCT_ID = PRODUCTS.PRODUCT_ID
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many solutions to this question, here are a couple of options:

1. Modify the source query (select "SQL Query" instead of "Table/View" in "Source Type") of the detail report. Join to the products table and add a the product_name column to the "SELECT" clause
2. Set the column type to select list and in the query set  product_id as return value and product_name as display value. Not that in this case you have a select list
3. Set the column attributes "Settings > Based On" to "Display Value of List of Values". The List of values can be defined on the page or be a shared component. Now the column will just be text field.

Comment: Hi Koen, thank you for your response. I've gone with your option 1 and tried to `INNER JOIN` the two tables but I am still receiving the same error. I've updated the post. Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: It is unclear what you changed - it seems you're just changing the source for SQL Expression for the column. That is not what I meant. I suggested changing the  *source query for the IG Report* to include the product name.  For some reason the option "SQL Expression" doesn't work as expected, all 3 of the suggested options are not using that.